# Possessing ego for being "scripturally righteous" or being a sinner (knowingly or unknowingly): Which of the two is worse?

Tags: scripture, dharma, sin, punyam, ego

We all commit in some way or another various sins (pāpa) and good acts (puṇya).

My question pertains to the situation:

Suppose one person, might be conducting themselves in all righteousness (dharmic), as per all injunctions of the scriptures. However, despite being righteous (as per scriptures), they have latent ego (ahaṃkāra) inside them of being "righteous".
Then there might be a second person who might be doing all kinds of sins (deliberately or non-deliberately), as per against the scriptural injunctions.

Sometimes people might have ahaṃkāra of being born in a certain social or gender setting. They might consider the other people as inferior, due to that ego.

Is the ahaṃkāra (ego) developed as a result of "being good or better" more worse and dangerous than the pāpa (sins) accumulated done via activities which oppose the Dharma?

Who between the two is the worst sinner? The one who's scripturally righteous, but with ahaṃkāra, or the one who is a sinner (unknowingly or unknowingly)? Does scriptures makes any such kind of distinction and explain them? Views of āchāryas and gurus are also welcome.

Comment: In your example one person has some good qualities but he is egoistic. But the other person seemingly only has bad qualities. You should specify some good qualities that he has in order that they can be compared. Right now it's looking like walkover.

Comment: Actually, the first person is dharmic but possess the ego of being dharmic (and they do know that). The other person might be committing sins knowingly or unknowingly. So, basically the question is : does the Ego of being righteous or dharmic surpass that of the sins of being adharmic, in other words, is ahaṃkāra of or about anything worse than any kinds of sins committed ? @Rickross

Comment: Then I think it is required to know what kind of sins the sinner have committed. Only then it is possible to compare. Otherwise it has to be shown that being egoistic is the greatest sin.

Comment: Well, sins obviously include anything which scriptures say so. And yes, ultimately it's to be shown if being Egoistic about one's own dharma, or conduct is the biggest of the sins or not? @Rickross

Comment: First you have to understand the desha, Kala before interpreting scriptures.Vedic scriptures were never to be written in the first place as it brings heavy chances of interpolation & lies from writers,hence they are called Shrutis or those heard from Gurus. All the scriptures are written in Kaliyuga(when Krishna left earth after 3000BC and end of 12000 Age of Leo/Kings) & Vedic religion was influenced because of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_Aquarius of 12000 years as Kaliyuga meant darkness and to bring Satyuga again,new research & questioning is to be done. http://www.dwapara-yuga.org

Comment: Very act of questioning(like done on this site or modern age) scriptures and writing scriptures is non-Vedic as its done with intellect, shrewdness but Vedic scriptures are revealed wisdom and learnt from Gurus or rishis in their gurukulas which are not present on large scale on earth today. Thats why Karma and Bhakti Yoga work better than Gyan Yoga in Kaliyuga.You can't be scripturally righteous as scriptures themselves are questionable in Kali, anyways going by scriptures is still better than doing actions based on majority society influenced by Western materialist culture after British rule

Comment: Arth and Kama are part of Materialism only, and are to be pursued as a part of the four Puruśharthas. So materialism is not a non - hindu concept. It's very well recognized and expected to be accepted as a part and parcel. Of course, one must strive for Mokșha ultimately. @Manu Kumar. The delusion that materialism isn't a part (although a small one) of hindu life is unfounded.

Comment: @Vivikta materialism is part of Hinduism, but rejection of varna-system, marriages for luxuries and wealth, divorces, pursuit of gathering several material equipments like cars and phones, deserting parents, settling in west are trends injected in Indian society from Western nations. Artha & Kama are based on Dharma given by enlightened gurus/Brahmins and scriptures not based on laws written by materialist government or aristocrats as done in the modern society and West. Thats why India was golden sparrow in the past because Artha & Kama are based & for spirituality(Dharma & Moksha) itself.

Comment: @Vivikta - Ego - is false identification (not pride). When we identify with something we have acquired (body, mind, designation, role...), it is called ego (ahamkara). So if one is identified with his good deeds, he remains Sattvic but still has to transcend that into Shuddha Sattva, without which there is no deliverance. If one unknowingly does lots of mistakes but is true to himself, he can very easily cross the tri-gunas into Shuddha Sattva because he gives utmost importance to "Satyam". Once Suddha Sattva is reached it's just a matter of time before one finds their Self.

Comment: @Siv, that's the advaita definition. Literal meanings and metaphysical connotations are to be treated differently.

Comment: @Manu Kumar, no one's forcing anyone to settle abroad. Ultimately it's the decision of the person by their own volition. More than "western influence", the problem lies with the person who gets influenced. Blaming other cultures for our own shortcomings is a misshapen approach.

Comment: @Vivikta these are open end debatable questions. My main point was to mention that scriptures are to be learnt from direct Guru and if you have a Guru, you wont be confused about righteousness unless the Guru is one of the modern sham who sits on golden throne and have a brainwashed cult.  However, the real Guru is always Omniscient Higher-Self or inner Atman. https://www.sriramanamaharshi.org/teachings/חסד/

Comment: Well, so long as you are genuinely listening to the scripture, and not forcing it to conform to your beliefs, I don't see how that's a bad thing. Also, understanding scripture is distinct from following it. I would the former is more important as otherwise you wouldn't know what to do when orders/recommendations of scripture contradict.